# Error in loading dll from JNI on windows 2008

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

We have a java program which depends on C++ code through JNI. We have .so and .dll for solaris and windows of C++ code placed in classpath of java program. 
Also on windows we have generated java.exe.manifest so as to force windows to use MSVC RTL. This works fine in solaris , windows 2003 but on windows 2008 I get error message that
'side by side assembly comnfiguration is wrong'

Here is java.exe.manifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50727.762' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Also I tried to debug problem through sxstrace and here is its log

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = D:\JDA\TRO\bin\OptCoreBodies.dll
    AssemblyDirectory = D:\JDA\TRO\bin\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File D:\JDA\TRO\bin\OptCoreBodies.dll.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0"
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_none_09c0f5a3facc9779.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.3053".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_none_88e044e32fae7230.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_none_88e044e32fae7230.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.3053".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.3053_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.3053_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\JDA\TRO\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\JDA\TRO\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\JDA\TRO\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\JDA\TRO\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Can anybody help me in resolving this problem. I tried installing MS VS 2005 Redistributable but no use.

Thanks In advance
Niraj Rathi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRT version you compiled with version='8.0.50727.762' and the system on which you are executing doesn't have this CRT version. So as @panickal mentioned installing `MS VS 2005 Redistributable Package` should resolve the issue.

Comment: I installed almost all redistributables of VC++ from 2005 to 2008. And I checked C:\Windows\WinSXS this directory is there on windows 2008 machine. amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_88e046c92fae6f57

Comment: @niraj in manifest file include <dependency> tag for processorArchitecture="amd64" and version="8.0.50727.4053"

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this Issue. I re-installed Operating System  then Installed Visual C++ 2005 Redistributables (x64) both SP1 too. And then Installed Java 64 bit. Then added HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMPONENTS\PreferExternalManifest registry and set it to 1.

After that issue got resolved.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `x64` variants of `MS VS 2005 Redistributable Package`.

There are four variants of MS VS 2005 Redistributable Package

- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21254)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18471)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3387)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5638)

Comment: I already installed X64 Redistributable packages but still same error. Let me try installing X86 Redistributable packages too.